# Interface Implement differences in C# vs Java

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a binding for a java library that comes as part of an SDK for a scanner, model Honeywell Dolphin CT50. However, I have run into a bit of rut in my understanding.

The following example is given in Java. The Create method expects a interface implementation. However, i am not aware of a similar way to override the 'onCreated' method of the interface while still accessing the class-wide variables. This is were i am having the trouble, how can i do the following in C#.

Java:

```
private static BarcodeReader barcodeReader;
private AidcManager manager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // create the AidcManager providing a Context and a
    // CreatedCallback implementation.
    AidcManager.create(this, new CreatedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreated(AidcManager aidcManager) {
            manager = aidcManager;
            barcodeReader = manager.createBarcodeReader();
        }
    });

}
```

In .NET, the compiler will not do as above and implement the interface as an anonymous type, thus I have to implement the interface. However, how can i then assign the class wide variables?

My C#:

```
NameSpace Scanner {
    private static BarcodeReader barcodeReader;
    private AidcManager manager;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

       CreateCallback callback = new CreateCallback() {  };
       AidcManager.Create(this, callback.OnCreated(AidcManager aidcManager));
    }

public class CreateCallback : AidcManager.ICreatedCallback
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void OnCreated(AidcManager p0)
    {
        // How can I initialize the manager and barcode reader variables in the class above from here?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you know how to do this in Java and are asking how to do it in C#?

Comment: Good point. I will edit. I want to know how to do this in C#

Comment: C# does not have anonymous classes. You would have to pass the arguments you want to capture to the constructor of your sub-class. I'm not 100% on the C# syntax, but I believe with the syntax `new CreateCallback() {  };` the `{ }` is an initializer list.

Comment: If the interface consists of a single method, then a more natural way to do it in C# would be via a delegate rather than an interface.

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem, but may help avoid future problems related to the following statement: You shouldn't have object instances assigning values to static members, as this could lead to confusion (which object was the the last one to assign it a value?). Why is `barcodeReader` static?

Comment: My guess would have to do with the how the aidcManager uses the scanner resources, can't be certain as of now. That is a great question I will have see if issues are caused without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a callback implementation `CreateCallback` that has a other callback as constructor parameter `successAction`. This passed callback `OnManagerCreated` will be called in the `OnCreated` of `CreateCallback`.

**Important Note:** If you implement a Java interface, you have to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`. Do **not** implement `Handle` and `Dispose()` on your own.

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity : Activity 
{
    private static BarcodeReader _barcodeReader;
    private AidcManager _manager;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        CreateCallback callback = new CreateCallback(OnManagerCreated) {  };
        AidcManager.Create(this, callback);
    }

    private void OnManagerCreated(AidcManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
        _barcodeReader = manager.CreateBarcodeReader();
    }
}
```

**Callback implementation**

```
public class CreateCallback : Java.Lang.Object, AidcManager.ICreatedCallback
{
    private Action<AidcManager> _successAction;
    public CreateCallback(Action<AidcManager> successAction)
    {
        _successAction = successAction;
    }

    public void OnCreated(AidcManager p0)
    {
        _successAction(p0);
    }
}
```

**Other possibility**

You can also implement the interface directly in your activity class like

```
public class MyActivity : Activity, AidcManager.ICreatedCallback 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the outer class instance to the constructor:

```
class test
{
    private static BarcodeReader barcodeReader;
    private AidcManager manager;

    public virtual void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // create the AidcManager providing a Context and a
        // CreatedCallback implementation.
        AidcManager.create(this, new CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClass(this));
    }

    private class CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClass : CreatedCallback
    {
        private readonly test outerInstance;

        public CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClass(test outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        public override void onCreated(AidcManager aidcManager)
        {
            outerInstance.manager = aidcManager;
            barcodeReader = outerInstance.manager.createBarcodeReader();
        }
    }
}
```